# Filament/Laravel: Passing and Updating Variables in Filament Action

Tags: php, laravel, filamentphp

I am new to Filament and working on creating a form that allows users to input a topic, language, and tone. I'm using the OpenAI API to generate a professional email based on these inputs.

The code below successfully opens a modal for users to enter this information, and the EmailGenerationService() class returns a JSON object containing the email title and content. So far, everything is working smoothly.

Now, after the action is completed, I want to open another modal to display the generated email. But I couldn't get it done. Here is my code

```php
Action::make('writeEmail')
            ->form([
                TextInput::make('mail_subject'),
                Select::make('mail_language')
                    ->enum(MailLanguages::class)
                    ->options(MailLanguages::class),
                Select::make('mail_tone')
                    ->enum(MailTones::class)
                    ->options(MailTones::class),
            ])
            ->action(function (array $data) {
                $prompt = 'Subject: '.$data['mail_subject'].'. Language: '.$data['mail_language']->value.'. Tone: '.$data['mail_tone']->value;
                $service = new EmailGenerationService($prompt, 2000);
                $mail['title'] = $service->title;
                $mail['content'] = $service->content;
                
                //here I want to add a code to open a new modal to show results
            })
            ->modalAlignment(Alignment::Center)
            ->closeModalByClickingAway(false);
```

Answer (score -2):

In order to open another modal after completing the action, you can use the `Modal` class from Filament to create a new modal and then return it as part of your action. Here's an example of how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```php
use Filament\Forms\Components\Modal;
use Filament\Forms\Components\ModalClose;
use Filament\Forms\Components\ModalContent;
use Filament\Forms\Components\ModalFooter;
use Filament\Forms\Components\ModalHeader;

Action::make('writeEmail')
    ->form([
        // ... (your existing form components)
    ])
    ->action(function (array $data) {
        $prompt = 'Subject: ' . $data['mail_subject'] . '. Language: ' . $data['mail_language']->value . '. Tone: ' . $data['mail_tone']->value;
        $service = new EmailGenerationService($prompt, 2000);
        $mail['title'] = $service->title;
        $mail['content'] = $service->content;

        // Create a new modal to display the generated email
        $modal = Modal::make('generatedEmailModal')
            ->title('Generated Email')
            ->open()
            ->component(ModalContent::make()->view('your-view-path', ['mail' => $mail]))
            ->component(ModalFooter::make()
                ->child(ModalClose::make('Close'))
            );

        // Return the modal to open it after completing the action
        return $modal;
    })
    ->modalAlignment(Alignment::Center)
    ->closeModalByClickingAway(false);
```

In this example, `your-view-path` should be replaced with the actual path to your Blade view file that will render the generated email. Ensure that you create the corresponding Blade view file that receives the `$mail` variable and displays the email title and content. This modal will be opened once the action is completed.